# Error en conexion a mi base de datos con jdbc: No suitable driver found forjdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

estoy intentando acceder a mi base de datos local en MySQL y me sigue dando un mismo error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC".
Tengo una clase que llama al archivo config.properties llamada configProperties(ya probe que funcionaba bien),mi problema surge en esta parte de mi clase SQLConnection dandome el error que aclare anteriormente.

```
  public class SQLConnection {
    private ConfigProperties configProperties;
    private Connection connection;


    // Constructor sin parámetros que obtiene valores de config.properties
    public SQLConnection() {
        configProperties = new ConfigProperties();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                // Obtener valores del archivo de propiedades
                String url = configProperties.properties("url");
                String user = configProperties.properties("user");
                String password = configProperties.properties("password");

                // Establecer la conexión
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,password);

                System.out.println("Conexion establecida con la base de datos");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

El url que tengo en el properties es el siguiente:
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC"

Comment: Mmmmmm, ¿`"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC"` o `"jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC"`? (a ver si notás la diferencia)

Comment: Ahí probé ambas y sigue el mismo error.

Comment: No es probar por probar... Uno tiene un typo, el otro no. Y por cierto... ¿Tenés el conector .jar en el classpath?

Comment: Lo conecto a traves de maven y ya tengo instalada la dependencia necesaria.

Comment: Lo que te quiere decir @padaleiana es que escribiste mal la cadena de conexión en `config.properties`, observa el mensaje de error: *`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC"`*, **después de `mysql` te faltan dos puntos: `:`**

Comment: Lo que quise decir yo ,es que probé con y sin los dos puntos delante del mysql y sigue tirando el mismo error.

Comment: Y ahí de nuevo, no es probar _por probar_...  Es tal cual como dice @A.Cedano. Solo para descartar problemas: ¿está corriendo el servicio de MySQL?

Comment: Estamos hablando de programación, y el mínimo detalle importa. No es posible que hayas probado de las dos maneras y **siga tirando el MISMO error**. El error es este *`java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC"`* si probaste con la cadena de conexión correcta, que sería esta: **`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/parcialProg?serverTimezone=UTC`** el error no puede decir lo mismo, si dice lo mismo, es porque **no estás cambiando el valor de la cadena de conexión en el lugar correcto**. Esa sencillez te puede hacer perder horas.

Comment: Tratándose de un archivo de configuraciones, pueden ocurrir cosas como que esté tomando otro archivo de otra parte. Tú cambias el dato en un archivo pero resulta que el programa lo toma de otro sitio. Por eso, pon puntos de interrupción en tu programa y revisa el valor de esos datos que están dando problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El url de conexion no es problema sino el driver, debes tomar en cuenta esto:

1. si tienes una aplicación de tipo JakartaEE el driver de conexion debes agregarlo en el servidor de aplicaciones (payara, glassfish, tomcat, etc)
2. Si tienes una aplicacion de escritorio debes agregar el driver en las librerias de la aplicacion.